# Is it possible to execute .jsx file through button in photoshop

Tags: vb.net, button, actionscript, photoshop

I have several action script files (.jsx) I want to create button to execute this script in Photoshop I have tried to make this button in vb.net I have tried this code...and add Photoshop object library as reference but there is something wrong. Please tell what is wrong with this code:

```
Dim PhotoshopApp As Photoshop.Application``
    Dim photoshopDoc As Photoshop.Document
    Dim curLayer As Photoshop.ArtLayer
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        System.diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\Super Soft.jsx")
    End Sub
```

Comment: please guide me I want to execute these action script through button in photoshop

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can using do JavaScript function in Photoshop document object:

```
  Dim app As New Photoshop.Application
  app.Dojavascript("C:\Super Soft.jsx")
```

Comment: this is an answer, rather a comment

Comment: well, in that case, provide a piece of code on how to do that.